# Nest.js - elasticsearch connection inside docker containers

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, nestjs

So I've been trying to connect my nest.js app to the elasticsearch connection but I have no idea why I can't.

```
app                | (node:30) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ConnectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.0.2:9200
app                |     at ClientRequest.onError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Connection.js:114:16)
```

This is the error I'm receiving. I'm composing my node.js app and elasticsearch engine in the same dockercompose file.

```yaml
//docker-compose.yml

version: "3"
services:

  app:
    container_name: app
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    command: npm run start:dev
    networks: 
      - elastic
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - es01

  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.9.1
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01 
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster 
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: redis
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
      
  redis-commander:
    container_name: redis-commander
    hostname: redis-commander
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
 
networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

```
//.env

ELASTICSEARCH_NODE=http://es01:9200
ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=admin
```

```
// backend nest.js implementation

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    ElasticsearchModule.registerAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        node: configService.get('ELASTICSEARCH_NODE'),
        auth: {
          username: configService.get('ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME'),
          password: configService.get('ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD'),
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [ContentSearchController],
  providers: [ContentSearchService],
  exports: [ElasticsearchModule, ContentSearchService],
})
```

This config was great, when I was developing my nest.js app externally (outside from docker-compose and using the localhost connection - http://localhost:9200).

Right now I was trying to move everything into dockerfile, I managed to achieve everything apart from this unfortunate connection with elasticsearch. Can anyone advice what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe there is something not right with the ELASTICSEARCH_NODE address but I have no idea what am I doing wrong

Comment: It's definitely a startup problem. The reason is: Nest server starts up before elastic search runs. When I restarted nest.js container everything started up just right.

I have no idea how could it be possible as I am depending on elasticsearch module in the docker-compose file. Any suggestions?

Comment: You already expose the container's port 9200 to the host, have you ever tried to change the `http://es01:9200` to `http://localhost:9200`?